# How can I create one column in my select output with sequence and seed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have one select like this

```
SELECT 
TOP (5)
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
 ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
ORDER BY S.Id
```

that have output Like this

```
RowNumber            SN
-------------------- --------
1                    01100017
2                    01100025
3                    01100033
4                    01100041
5                    01100050
(5 row(s) affected)
```

And I Have another select Like this

```
 SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
 ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
 ORDER BY S.Id
 OFFSET (5) ROWS
FETCH NEXT (5) ROWS ONLY;
```

that have output Like this

```
RowNumber            SN
-------------------- --------
6                    01100068
7                    01100076
8                    01100084
9                    01100092
10                   01100106
(5 row(s) affected)
```

how I can Union All Two up select and get result like this

```
RowNumber            Sn
-------------------- --------
1                    01100017
6                    01100068
2                    01100025
7                    01100076
3                    01100033
8                    01100084
4                    01100041
9                    01100092
5                    01100050
10                   01100106
(10 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP (5)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
        ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
    FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 5
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
         ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
    FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
    ORDER BY S.Id
    OFFSET (5) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (5) ROWS ONLY
    ) X
ORDER BY (RowNumber-1)%5, RowNumber;
```

Edit: this works now

Comment: this is not true . your output is 1,6,7,2,3,8,9,4,5,10.but i want get 1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,10,5

Comment: @Shahgholi.Ardalan: ah yes, copy paste error from my test script. Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
    TOP (5)
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
     ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
    FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
    ORDER BY S.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
     ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
    FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
     ORDER BY S.Id
     OFFSET (5) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (5) ROWS ONLY
)x
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RowNumber-5<=0 THEN RowNumber ELSE RowNumber-5 END, RowNumber
```

Rather, this will solve your issue I guess

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
    TOP (10)
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By S.Id) AS RowNumber 
     ,S.SubscribeNumber AS SN
    FROM billing.Subscribe AS S
    ORDER BY S.Id
)x
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RowNumber-5<=0 THEN RowNumber ELSE RowNumber-5 END, RowNumber
```